# (python error code) slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Tags: python, anaconda

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xxfZ.png)[enter image description here][2]    (base) C:\Users\aaa\TPU-Posenet>pose_camera_single_tpu.py --videofile video1.mp4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\aaa\TPU-Posenet\pose_camera_single_tpu.py", line 122, in 
        res, inference_time = engine.DetectPosesInImage(prepimg)
      File "C:\Users\aaa\TPU-Posenet\pose_engine.py", line 126, in DetectPosesInImage
        outputs = [output[i:j] for i, j in zip(self._output_offsets, self._output_offsets[1:])]
      File "C:\Users\aaa\TPU-Posenet\pose_engine.py", line 126, in 
        outputs = [output[i:j] for i, j in zip(self._output_offsets, self._output_offsets[1:])]
    TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

---

In Windows Python, 
we are working on a project to detect objects in the image with anaconda prompt. Currently, 
the development environment is all built up and the last code is left, 
but we can't move forward thanks to this error code.

I'm still working on it, but I'm not making any progress. What's the problem? Maybe this is the problem numpy version.. help guys

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xxfZ.png)

Comment: Please, show your code

Comment: What kind of source code? Pose_camera_single_tpu.py?

Comment: The code, that cause the error

Comment: pose_camera_single_tpu.py / There is an error in . 122nd line .                               I attached the image to Imgur.

Comment: As you see line 122 contain only call of `engine.DetectPosesInImage`. Can you show the part of code raises an exception?

Comment: The error code of the exception is also attached. line 126

Answer (score -1):

The reason is your code has a for loop inside of an index. You can't put for loops inside of indexes. list[for i,j]. At least, not in that way. With lists, you can only put integers as parameters for indexes in that way. So list[integer:integer] is acceptable but what you've done is not.

`outputs = [output[i:j] for i, j in zip(self._output_offsets, self._output_offsets[1:])]`

If you're trying to make a list as [output[i:j], for argument] this will not work because for is a keyword. Python thinks your trying to put a for loop inside of a list.

Comment: I tried to modify the code, but there was no change in the error code.

Comment: I looked at your code, perhaps it's something I did not know about python, but why did you put your for loop inside your output index? I don't think you can put loop functions inside of indexes.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It sounds like you haven't heard of list comprehensions.